# Spring @Controller and custom MethodNameResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have several controllers in a spring mvc application. They are regular beans that inherit from `MultiActionController`. They also have a custom `MethodNameResolver` that inspects a certain request parameter.

Now I am trying to use a new controller - a pojo with `@Controller` annotation. I am using `@RequestMapping` to resolve methods.

I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but as explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced) in the spring reference, it is possible to use `@RequestMapping` with various filters (e.g. GET vs POST) without specifying a path, and then if a url applies to several methods then Spring falls back to `InternalPathMethodNameResolver` to decide which method to invoke.

How can I tell Spring to fall back to my custom `MethodNameResolver`? Is it enough to inject the resolver to my pojo controller?
(my controller doesn't inherit from any Spring specific class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to declare `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` bean and set its `methodNameResolver` property.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, in combination with DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping