# How to replace <mvc:annotation-driven/> with custom beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As I understand from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is just a shortcut for registering `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` and some other things.

My question is: how I can manually define same functionality as provides `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` without using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` ?

I.e. I need example of Spring configuration which defines and configures all the beans implicitly created by `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` shortcut. In other words I need compiled version of  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` (with all default values).

P.S. I need it because  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is not so flexible and doesn't provide ways to configure implicitly registered beans (I want to configure `alwaysUseFullPath` property of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`)

Comment: Which is pretty easy to do. Create a bean implementing `BeanPostProcessor` check in the `postProcessBeforeInitialization` if the bean is of the type you need, set the additional properties. Which is a lot easier then trying to configure all the things the namespace does.

Answer (score 2):

You can even do it without manually configuring everything. Just configure the `UrlPathHelper` and set it on the configuration.

```
<bean id="urlPathHelper" class="org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
<bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven path-helper="urlPathHelper" />
```

If that doesn't work because you are on an older spring version use a `BeanPostProcessor` and in its `postProcessBeforeInitialization` do the additional settings/init you want. It would be to cumbersome to do trying to recreate all the options of `<mvc:annotation-driven />so, just to set a single property. Instead create a bean which implements`BeanPostProcessor`

```
public class WebMvcConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean).setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
    }
}
```

Just add this bean to your xml configuration and be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by removing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag and define your all bean explicitly using `<bean>` tag and other helping tag.

Also see this [Howto get rid of <mvc:annotation-driven />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693397/howto-get-rid-of-mvcannotation-driven)

Comment: The link is for an old version of `<mvc:annotation-driven />` some of the classes mentioned in there are deprecated and are already removed from the upcoming Spring 5 release.

Comment: @M.Deinum yah... I shared it because I though it may helps OP.